# Exception on native thread crashes .Net application without exception

Tags: .net, exception, interop

I have discovered a scenario where my .Net application will crash unexpectedly without raising any exceptions. I would like that, at least, `AppDomain.UnhandledException` worked in this case, in order to enable me at least to log the error and present the user with some information.

In this scenario, I have an .Net assembly (let's call it **A**) with an interop call to a  native DLL (which we will call **B**). B creates a thread and throws; Without anyone to catch the exception, I'd expect it to go all the way up the stack, back into my managed application, and then finally become an unhandled exception.

At this point I would expect the OS to hand the control back to .Net, which would call `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and, with that, my application would end. However, the call is never made.

**Below I included enough information to reproduce the issue. It can be ignored.**

*Program.cs*

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += _currentDomainUnhandledException;
        try
        {
            BugDllInterop.ErrorMethod(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.GetType().Name);
        }            

        Console.WriteLine("Clean exit.");
    }

    private static void _currentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception trapped.");
    }
}
```

*BugDllInterop.cs*

```
public static class BugDllInterop
{
    private const string BUG_DLL = "InteropExceptions.BugDll.dll";

    [DllImport(BUG_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void ErrorMethod(int i);
}
```

*BugDll.h*

```
// INCLUSION GUARD
#pragma once

#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport) 

extern "C" 
{
    DllExport void ErrorMethod(int i);
}
```

*BugDll.cpp*

```
// HEADER /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "BugDll.h"

// LIBRARIES //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DWORD WINAPI threadMethod(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    throw 0;

    return 0;
}

void ErrorMethod(int i)
{

    DWORD myThreadID;
    HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, threadMethod, 0, 0, &myThreadID);
    WaitForSingleObject(myHandle, 3000);
    CloseHandle(myHandle);

}
```

Again, my desired is just that the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event is raised. Of course, if anyone knows how to properly *handle* the exception in order to keep the application alive, it would be even better.

Comment: Just to directly address the conceptual misunderstanding... "I'd expect it to go all the way up the stack, back into my managed application"  The new thread has its own separate stack, the function creating the thread and the C# code calling that function are not on the call stack that matters (and they might even have returned before the new thread errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't catch and manage exception thrown from another unmanaged thread.

When a method throws an exception the CLR will search for a handler **only in the thread where the exception has been thrown**. It's even understandable because the call stack of a thread begins with the thread itself.

You have a *root* exception handler because the CLR puts a handler at the top level (the one will invoke your filter) but **this isn't true for unmanaged threads** so **their exception can't be forwarded**.

The only solution for this situation is to catch exception in the thread where they are originated. If your thread function can throw an exception then add a catch there. Anyway not on the managed side. Managed/unmanaged boundaries are pretty thick here.

You  may like to read this nice article about exception handling: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Adriano! That does explain the problem.